# Windows 7 cmd.exe can run java command ,but Intellij terminal Java command not found and error

Tags: java, intellij-idea, windows-7, environment-variables

Using Intellij IDE 15, I can't run java command, and Intellij IDE Terminal report that java is not recognized as an internal or external command. I'm confused why windows 7 CMD terminal can run normally? Intellij IDE can't do this.

Comment: What is the result of `java -version` in IntelliJ IDE terminal?

Comment: java is not recognized as an internal or external command

Answer (score 1):

Run command `echo %Path%` in the terminal and check that jdk bin folder is shown in command output. If it is not show then add %JAVA_HOME%\bin\ to the system environment Path and restart Intellij IDE or just restart Intellij IDE if Path variable contains necessary path.

Comment: System bin is ok, windows 7 CMD Terminal is OK, Only Intellij IDE terminal  work wrong.

Answer (score -1):

In the terminal, are you in the jdk/bin folder before doing the command?

Check if $JAVA_HOME is set on the environment variables, also check if you have the correct path to the jdk in Intellij.

Comment: java set system environment, don't need to jdk/bin path

Comment: Window 7 CMD terminal is OK, Only Intellij IDE terminal.